# Mapping objects in ng-value and ng-model (Angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

An old code to display the radio boxes on angular side was written like this before:

```
<label ng-repeat="item in items" class="col-xs-3">
    <input type="radio" name="{{item.name}}"
           value="{{item}}"
           ng-change="saveRadio(x,y,z)"
           ng-model="data[item.name]">
    {{item.name}}
</label>
```

The problem was `item` is an object and the function `saveRadio` used to save the object in text format. We tried substituting the `value` with `ng-value` as below. Now preselection of saved answer is not happening. Code is shown below:

```
<label ng-repeat="item in items" class="col-xs-3">
    <input type="radio" name="{{item.name}}"
           ng-value="item"
           ng-change="saveRadio(x,y,z)"
           ng-model="data[item.name]">
    {{item.name}}
</label>
```

The `scope` variable data has the array of answers map.

Am I missing something here or is there something more to be added for Object comparison?

Comment: what is the  saved answer (data[item.name]) for the radio ?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out, apparently ng-model and ng-value can store objects but doesn't do object comparison. Adding a ng-checked with the unique value will preselect the radiobox like so:

```
<label ng-repeat="item in items" class="col-xs-3">
    <input type="radio" name="{{item.name}}"
           ng-value="item"
           ng-checked="item.option == data[item].option)"
           ng-change="saveRadio(x,y,z)"
           ng-model="data[item.name]">
    {{item.name}}
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the goal with this approach also:

```
$scope.items = [{id:1,name:"first"}];

$scope.savedAnswer = {id:1,name:"first"}; 

var index = $scope.items.map(function(obj, index) {
    if(obj.name == $scope.savedAnswer.name) {
        return index;
    }
}).filter(isFinite);

$scope.preselectedAnswer = $scope.items[index];
```

**View**

```
<label ng-repeat="item in items" class="col-xs-3">
    <input type="radio" name="{{item.name}}"
           ng-value="item"
           ng-change="saveRadio(x,y,z)"
           ng-model="preselectedAnswer">
    {{item.name}}
</label>
```

plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/83atxi7JGtyBSlRqK2xo?p=preview